# Hi how can i diagnose smps fault

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, troubleshooting

is possible to diagnose/pinpoint faulty components on a smps example lcd tv powerboard using the rosin atomiser short finder techique as i was under the impression that all faulty components on a pcb get hot when shorted but also if they are faulty or is this not the case thanx

Comment: _"i was under the impression that all faulty components on a pcb get hot when shorted but also if they are faulty"_ - No.

Comment: Most of the dud TV’s I’ve seen nothing gets hot as the main mosfet has exploded and the fuse has blown. My first technique is to use my eyes to see if anything is burn or damaged. I use ny ears to listen for any ticking or strange sounds. My nose to smell if anything is hot or burning. Then a multimeter.